# UILabel shows fewer lines then expected with multiple lines mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, uilabel

I'd like my `UILabel` to show my data in multiple lines, and the data is fetch from txt file.
I've searched online for this question, and all the answers show that I just need to set `lineBreakMode` to `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` and `numberOfLines` = 0. However, the problem is that, even though I added these settings, the labels shows fewer lines than expected (my data has 4 lines, however the label only shows 2 lines). Here's my code:

```
-(void)updateFileContentLabel:(NSString*)content{

    self.fileContentLabel.text = content;
    self.fileContentLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    self.fileContentLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f];
    self.fileContentLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    [self.fileContentLabel sizeToFit];

    NSLog(@"file Label: %@",self.fileContentLabel.text);


}
```

As you see, I have a NSLog to show the content of label's text. And the text of label in `NSLog` is correct (4 lines). However on the phone or simulator, it only shows 2 lines instead of 4. Does anyone know where is the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your `UILabel` is just not big enough. Solutions:

1.Increase a `label size`.

2.Add following code to allow `UILabel` to decrease the font size if needed.

```
self.fileContentLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5;
```

Comment: It works! Thank you!! So it seems that if the size of label is not big enough, it would just ignore some data right? If I set the size of label to the size of the screen, then if the data is even larger, the label would not support a scroll to show the data right?

Answer (score 0):

I was only able to replicate your problem when I was using auto layout and didn't have constraints set up for fileContentLabel, so check that out.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I found that it is unwise to use UILabel to show data with large size. So I changed it to TextView. Then problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method to calculate the height of text and set the frame of label accordingly.

```
 - (CGSize)boundingSizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
 {
CGSize stringSize;

if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:)]) {

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = lineBreakMode;

    NSDictionary * stringAttributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: font, paragraphStyle: NSParagraphStyleAttributeName};

    stringSize = [self boundingRectWithSize:size
                                    options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                 attributes:stringAttributes context:nil].size;

    stringSize = CGSizeMake(ceil(stringSize.width), ceil(stringSize.height) + 2);

} else {

    stringSize = [self sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:size lineBreakMode:lineBreakMode];

}

return stringSize;
}
```